# Thumbnail slider with pure css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just created the css to display in a carousel / slider if the images pass the div but Im not able to create arrows next and back to play thumbs one by one

here is my full css and html without javascript code https://jsfiddle.net/vydxam3y/

I dont know what to use as javascript to complete this.

this is my css:

```
.thumbnail-slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: visible;
    *zoom: 1
}
.thumbnail-slider ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:2000em}
.thumbnail-slider ul li {
    float: left;
}
.thumbnail-slider .thumb+a {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow {
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 52;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out false;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out false;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow.arrow-left:after,
.thumbnail-slider .arrow.arrow-right:after {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 0;
    text-align: center
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow.arrow-right {
    right: 0px
}
.noTouch .thumbnail-slider:hover .arrow {
    opacity: 1
}
.noTouch .thumbnail-slider ul {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out false;
    -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out false;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out
}
.touch .thumbnail-slider {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto
}
.touch .thumbnail-slider .arrow {
    display: none !important
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow:after {
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow {
    top: 42px
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow:after {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow.arrow-left:after {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
.thumbnail-slider .arrow.arrow-right:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list img {
    display: block
}
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li.face {
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 165px;
    width: 113px
}
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li.channel,
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li.category {
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 165px;
    width: 180px
}
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0
}
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li.category img,
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li.face img,
.thumbnail-slider .video-tag-list li.channel img {
    height: 134px
}
.thumbnail-slider .thumb {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3px
}
.thumbnail-slider .thumb:before {
    content: ""
}
.thumbnail-slider .name {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word
}
.noTouch .video-tag-list li:hover .thumb:before,
.noTouch .video-tag-list li.active .thumb:before {
    border-width: 3px
}
.noTouch .video-tag-list .thumb:before {
    border: 0 solid #00b1ff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 51;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out false;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out false;
    transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out
}
.noTouch .video-tag-list .thumb {
    position: relative
}
```

should I use jquery? or its possible also with pure css?

Comment: I hope you realize quickly that js is magic that makes a slider to slide...

Comment: yes  @morels but Im looking to use minimal javascript options but in the tutorials around internet I see many examples with a large javascript file which effects on pagespeed of the website

Comment: thanks @AlexG Im going to check that topic

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Thanks I've seen it but couldnt work with this one however my css is just ready the only thing missed is the javascript and Im looking to find the usage with minimal javascript codes

Answer (score 0):

Hey why not you adopt the **owlcarousel** for your thumbnail slider.

It's very easy to use...check out demos here:
http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo